# OkHttp spdy support? response.protocol()

Tags: java, okhttp

when I was looking for a Spdy client, I found okhttp. I have just started to try it. My question is when I run GetExample.java as below,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;


public class GetExample {
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

  String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response.protocol());
    return response.body().string();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GetExample example = new GetExample();
    String response = example.run("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println(response.length());
  }
}
```

response.protocol() always returns, http/1.1 , why it doesn't return spdy? and is there a way to force client to use only spdy?

Answer (score -1):

Are you working on desktop Java or on Android? SPDY requires a library called ALPN-boot on desktop Java. On Android, you'll need v5.0 or above which is the earliest release that contains a stable implementation of ALPN. More details are here:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Building

Comment: Thank you, I am working on desktop Java, I could get spdy protocol with using ALPN. Do you know is there anyway to force client to use only spdy?

Comment: `OkHttpClient.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.SPDY_3))`

Comment: ... actually I think we require HTTP/1.1 as a fallback. Not sure if that approach is still valid.

Comment: In that case, it gives this error "protocols doesn't contain http/1.1: [spdy/3.1]"

Comment: Is there a way to set primary & fallback protocols?